# find a previous element if an element is undefined in HashMap

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I have a HashMap

```js
const hash = {
  "00:00": "Hello",
  "00:01": "Every one",
  "00:04": "Nice to meet you",
  "00:10": "Could you introduce yourself?",
  "00:23": "Hi, My name is HashMap"
}
console.log(hash["00:00"]);
console.log(hash["00:01"]);
console.log(hash["00:04"]);
console.log(hash["00:05"]); // it returns `undefined`, so it should find previous element. in this case "00:04"
console.log(hash["00:10"]);
console.log(hash["00:17"]); // it also returns `undefined`, it should find "00:10" element.
console.log(hash["00:19"]); // it also should find "00:10" element.
console.log(hash["00:22"]); // it also should find "00:10" element.
console.log(hash["00:23"]);
```

Thanks in advance

**Edited**

I don't want to iterate all elements. because it has no meaning with `HashMap`.

Comment: *"I don't want to iterate all elements. because it has no meaning with HashMap"*... according to that logic, *"previous element"* has no meaning either.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I understand, I've just wanted to know any "Special Algorithm" for this. because I don't know every algorithm in this world.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado so you mean, there is no way to solve my question with time complexity `O(1)` or under `O(n)`?

Comment: Are you fine with using libraries?

Comment: @hev1 maybe:) I just want to keep time complexity

Comment: @jinongun by "previous element" do you mean the previously accessed property or the previous alphabetical property?

Comment: @Ezra It means previous alphabetical property. I am sorry to make you confused.

Comment: @jinongun okay, I updated my solution accordingly. I realize it's not the performance you were hoping to get out of a HashMap, but I think it at least answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get by with a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). It allows you to intercept and redefine operations on an object. Using your example, it could look something like this:

```js
let hash = {
  "00:00": "Hello",
  "00:01": "Every one",
  "00:04": "Nice to meet you",
  "00:10": "Could you introduce yourself?",
  "00:23": "Hi, My name is HashMap"
}
const handler = {
  // Keeps track of last property accessed
  last: undefined,
  get: function (obj, prop) {
    if (prop in obj) {
      // Exists, so update last accessed property
      this.last = obj[prop];
      return obj[prop];
    }
    // Because there is no matching property, return last accessed
    return this.last;
  }
}
// Implement proxy
hash = new Proxy(hash, handler);

console.log(hash["00:00"]);  // Hello
console.log(hash["00:01"]);  // Every  one
console.log(hash["00:04"]);  // Nice to meet you
console.log(hash["00:05"]);  // Nice to meet you
console.log(hash["00:10"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["00:17"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["00:19"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["00:22"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["00:23"]);  // Hi, My name is HashMap
```

### Edit (after clarification of the question)

To find the nearest previous property, there's not a whole lot that can be done that doesn't involve iterating through at least some of the keys. This implementation uses a binary search, but I think it'd still be considered `O(n)` based off the likely definition of `Object.keys()`. I bumped up the keys by an hour, so you see the result of attempting to access a value less than anything defined.

```js
let hash = {
  "01:00": "Hello",
  "01:01": "Every one",
  "01:04": "Nice to meet you",
  "01:10": "Could you introduce yourself?",
  "01:23": "Hi, My name is HashMap"
}
const handler = {
  get: function (obj, prop) {
    if (obj[prop] !== undefined) {
      return obj[prop];
    } else {
      // Validate input format before bothering to search
      if (/\d{2}:\d{2}/.test(prop) !== true) return undefined;
      
      // Search for nearest previous property
      const keys = Object.keys(obj);
      return obj[findPrevious(keys, prop, 0, keys.length)];
    }
  }
}

function findPrevious(keys, prop, start, end) {
  // No previous key is available, so bail out
  if (start > end) return undefined;
  
  const middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
  const current = keys[middle];
  const next = keys[middle + 1];
  
  // Previous property is found or is the maximum defined
  if (current < prop && (next > prop || next === undefined)) {
    return keys[middle];
  }
  
  // Otherwise, keep searching
  if (keys[middle] > prop) {
    return findPrevious(keys, prop, start, middle - 1);
  } else {
    return findPrevious(keys, prop, middle + 1, end);
  }
}
// Implement proxy
hash = new Proxy(hash, handler);

console.log(hash["00:01"]);  // undefined
console.log(hash["01:00"]);  // Hello
console.log(hash["01:01"]);  // Every  one
console.log(hash["01:04"]);  // Nice to meet you
console.log(hash["01:05"]);  // Nice to meet you
console.log(hash["01:10"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["01:17"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["01:19"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["01:22"]);  // Could you introduce yourself?
console.log(hash["01:23"]);  // Hi, My name is HashMap
console.log(hash["10:00"]);  // Hi, My name is HashMap
```

If reads are more common than writes, you could store the result of `Object.keys()` on the handler and set it on each insert, but that would make any inserts become `O(n)` and reads `O(log(n))`. You would also need to define the keys when the Proxy is created, otherwise it'll just be an empty array.

Comment: Excellent :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Question. Is `Proxy` necessary? because I have no knowledge about that.

Comment: @jinongun it's only necessary if you want to make it look like it's just an Object having its property accessed. In this case, the Proxy simply gives you control over when a property is attempted to be accessed. It's similar to calling a function with the object as an argument (something like `findSameOrPrevious(hash, "00:00"`) but with a simpler interface.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const hash = {
  "00:00": "Hello",
  "00:01": "Every one",
  "00:04": "Nice to meet you",
  "00:10": "Could you introduce yourself?",
  "00:23": "Hi, My name is HashMap"
}


function x(time, check) {
    var prev = -1;
    var i;
    for (i in time) {
        var n = i;
        if ((prev != -1) && (check < n))
            return prev;
        else 
            prev = n;
    }
}

console.log(x(hash, "00:05"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to iterate all elements.

Answer (score 1):

I Think this is exactly what you need you will be able to retrieve from the hash, **without looping through the hash** and it takes into consideration the hours and minutes so you can insert any hours/minutes

```js
const hash = {
  "00:00": "Hello",
  "00:01": "Every one",
  "00:04": "Nice to meet you",
  "00:10": "Could you introduce yourself?",
  "00:23": "Hi, My name is HashMap"
}


function gethrmin(key){
  ka=key.split(':')
  a=ka[0].charAt(0) ,b=ka[0].charAt(1), c=ka[1].charAt(0), d=ka[1].charAt(1) ,prev=""
  h= a =='0' && b=='0'?0:(a=='0' && b!='0'?parseInt(b):parseInt(ka[0])) 
  m= c =='0' && d=='0'?0:(c=='0' && d!='0'?parseInt(d):parseInt(ka[1]))
}
function prevTi(){
  return h<9&&h!=0 && m==0?prev="0"+`${h-1}`+":"+"59":( h>9 && m==0?prev=`${h-1}`+":"+"59":(h==0 && m==0?prev="23:59":(h==0 && m<9 &&m!=0?prev="00:"+"0"+`${m-1}`:(h==0 && m>9 &&m!=0?prev="00:"+`${m-1}`:(h<9 && h!=0 || m<9&& m!=0 ?prev="0"+h+":"+"0"+`${m-1}`:(h>9 && h!=0 || m>9 && m!=0 ?prev=h+':'+`${m-1}`:(h>9 && h!=0 || m<9 && m!=0 ?prev=h+':'+"0"+":"+`${m-1}`:(h<9 && h!=0 || m>9 && m!=0 ?prev="0"+h+':'+m:null))))))))
 }
function checkdb(key){
  if(!hash[key]){
    gethrmin(key)
    nk=prevTi()
   return checkdb(nk)
}
else
  return hash[key]
}
function _(key){
  if(hash[key]) return hash[key]
    return checkdb(key)

}
console.log(_('00:00'))
console.log(_('00:01'))
console.log(_('00:04'))
console.log(_('00:05'))
console.log(_('00:10'))
console.log(_('00:17'))
console.log(_('00:19'))
console.log(_('00:22'))
console.log(_('22:22'))
```